# Why isn't my MySQL data being displayed within my PHP code?

Tags: php, mysql

I have working on a mySQL search and then display the information accordingly within my PHP code to display it into my website however what I try to do so I get no results displayed. Before the code worked when I was only working with one table but when executing a join it would not work. I feel like I am not doing this correctly anymore and have searched for an answer but to no dismay. Here is the entire MySQL and PHP code at work and the error I get when I used both ini_set('display_errors','On') and the ini_set('error_reporting',E_ALL);

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT 
    projects.ProjectName, 
    projects.ProjectLogo, 
    projects.ProjectLink, 
    projects.ProjectDescription, 
    entries.EntryNum, 
    entries.Votes, 
    entries.Views, 
    entries.Update 
FROM    projects 
        INNER JOIN entries 
            ON  projects.ProjectID = entries.ProjectID 
        INNER JOIN  
        (
            SELECT  a.ProjectID, MAX(a.Update) max_val
            FROM    entries a
            GROUP   BY a.ProjectID
        ) b ON  b.ProjectID = entries.ProjectID AND
                b.max_val = entries.Update
WHERE   projects.Media = 'image' AND 
        projects.Type = 'fan-art' 
ORDER   BY entries.Update DESC");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "
        <a href=\"" . $row['projects.ProjectLink'] . "\" >
         <div onMouseOver=\"description('" . $row['projects.ProjectName'] .  "', '" . $row['projects.ProjectDescription'] .  "', '" . (int)$row['entries.EntryNum'] .  "', '" . (int)$row['entries.Votes'] .  "', '" . $row['entries.Update'] .  "', '" . "')\" style=\"width: 140px; height: 130px; float: left; margin: 0px 5px 5px 0px;\">
          <img src=\"../" . $row['projects.ProjectLogo'] . "\" style=\"margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;\" />
         </div>
        </a>
    ";
}
```

One of the error is

Notice: Undefined index: projects.ProjectLink in /home/a3027546/public_html/images/fanart.php on line 43

Comment: I believe `$row['projects.ProjectLink']` should be -> `$row['ProjectLink']` and same with the other `$row`'s

Comment: It would not work because I am using two tables instead of one

Comment: For the query use `projects.foo` and the echoing use what is after the `.` if that don't work add `projects.ProjectLink AS 'ProjectLink'` to your query and use the example I stated earlier.

Comment: An SQL *result set* consists of a single set of columns, regardless of which *tables* they originated in. By default, the columns in the result set will be named after the columns in the underlying tables (but *not* named after the tables themselves); you can name them explicitly using the `AS` keyword. In other words `SELECT projects.ProjectLink ...` is the same as `SELECT projects.ProjectLink AS ProjectLink ...`.

Comment: `print_r($row)` and you know what you get

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe array names can have a `.` (dot) in them (or it could just be that the array being fetched doesn't include the `table.` prefix) and causing a error in your code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['projects.ProjectLink'] ...
    $row['projects.ProjectName'] ...
    $row['projects.ProjectDescription'] ...
    (int)$row['entries.EntryNum'] ...
    (int)$row['entries.Votes'] ...
     $row['entries.Update'] ...
    $row['projects.ProjectLogo']
}
```

should be:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['ProjectLink'] ...
    $row['ProjectName'] ...
    $row['ProjectDescription'] ...
    (int)$row['EntryNum'] ...
    (int)$row['Votes'] ...
     $row['Update'] ...
    $row['ProjectLogo']
}
```

If that doesn't work add something like `projects.ProjectLink AS 'ProjectLink'` to each of your select items and use the above solution.

Comment: They can have arbitrary text, that's why they're quoted.